# Pandora app fails to open after being used

Tags: 7.0-nougat, alarm, pandora

New phone, LG V20 from T-mobile. Android Nougat (7.0 right now). Latest Pandora app.

The problem first manifested when I expected Pandora to wake me the next morning. It didn't. Checking my phone the Snooze/Stop circle buttons were there on the lock screen as if Pandora was running, but there was no music or even the tone Pandora plays when it can't access Internet.

Later, using Pandora during the day I found that if I'd used Pandora closed it (either by pressing the X in the notification or just by leaving it alone and paused long enough the OS closed it) and then opened it several hours later or the next day, the app would begin loading but would not progress beyond the splash screen.

I have removed the app and reinstalled. I have cleared cache/data.

I have not reset the phone.

Silent hours are set up but not for alarms and they stop before the alarm goes off.

**Update 1**

I set the phone Clock app alarm for the same time as the Pandora alarm. The phone alarm will go off briefly, then Pandora will start playing music, then once the first song is done on Pandora the phone's alarm cuts over Pandora and starts sounding again.

*Odd.*

I also changed Quiet Hours so they end 5 minutes before the alarm goes off (Alarms are allowed to sound through Quiet Hours already).

Yesterday I completed a full remove/reinstall of Pandora but forgot to re-enable the Pandora alarm. I'll do more testing today.

Future steps involve a full wipe/reset of the phone (don't really want to do this for another month though, after I've got the full unlock from TMobile completed).

**Update 2**

I contacted Pandora support. The steps they took me through were:

- Update Pandora App to latest version.
- Disable any battery saver or task manager. Android Nougat has a built-in Battery Optimzations function, and the ability to allow specific apps to ignore the optimizations. I enabled ignoring optimizations for the Pandora App.
- Clear data.
- Verify app is installed in local memory (not external/storage card).
- Switch between normal and HQ audio (this is a data network-specific setting, and I'm using home wireless, but still switched it).
- Uninstall and reinstall.

After completing all these without improvement or resolution, Pandora support asked for details of my phone and software and forwarded this to the engineering team.

Two days later (Monday this week) the Pandora alarm worked perfectly, and again Tuesday. The phone had been running for perhaps 5-7 days this point without a restart.

Wednesday morning the issues reoccurred. The Alarm interface loaded on the lock screen but no sounds playing. Thursday was the same, and battery usage was very high that morning with Android Operating System using the lion's share. I restarted the phone Thursday, and this morning there was also no alarm.

I would advise you to report your own issues to Pandora support so they'll be more aware of the breadth of the issue.

Comment: Any update on this? I haven't been able to use the Pandora alarm since upgrading, and now on the S8, it still doesn't work

Comment: Just added Update 2 above. If you haven't already, contact Pandora support. If they can fix it for you, great. If not, they'll have more information to forward to their devs.

Comment: I tried using Sound Profiler to start Pandora for me, but it didn't work. Then the other day, I got an update from T-Mobile, and it started working again. Not sure​ if Pandora is starting itself with the alarm, or if it's Sound Profiler. I disabled Sound Profiler, so I'll see if the alarm works tomorrow.